# Change xml drawables colors dynamically

Tags: android

I have a xml shape in drawable folder

```
<shape 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <corners android:radius="0dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/very_light_gray" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dip"
        android:color="@color/dark_gray" />
</shape>
```

how can i change `very_light_gray` and `dark_gray` color programmatically?
is there any way? 
Is this possible with overriding shape class and using overrided class instead of shape in xml?

Comment: Create separate xml files for it in `drawable` folder, and use `setBackgroundResource` to change dynamically. If you don't do this, the shape will be changed on using`setBackgroundColor`

Comment: so it will dynamically change of colors?

Comment: yes, it will change background